# Point checking vs. Equation Raycasting Efficency

Tags: optimization, raycasting

I have a project where I need to detect what other creature(if any) a 2D creature is looking at. I have already implemented a Quadtree to assist in these approaches. I have two proposed methods:

1. Point Checking by checking several points along a line against a small amount of creatures. Whichever it finds first is returned
2. Equation based by checking if any creatures within a certain range intersect with a line by solving mx+b=sqrt(r^2-(x-x1)^2)+y1. But for this to work I would have to:

   - convert view into line
   - get quad roots and check b^2-4ac >=0
   - make sure other seen creature isn't behind view creature
   - check set of creatures that follow this to see which is closest
   - return that

My end question is: What ends up being the most efficient considering all factors and why?

Notes:

This project is specifically in Java but I am curious whether language matters.
The result should be per ray and is being used as input for a neural net.

Comment: Oh I see, apologies - I mistakenly thought the quadtree was itself an alternative to the equation method. The equation approach is not only the more efficient but the only *correct* approach - with the ray cast approach you can only determine the visible creatures with finite accuracy. But the standard way to do this is with "frustum culling", where only tree nodes within the player's field of view are checked.

Comment: If you can explain why raycasting wouldn't work in an answer I will mark it as correct.

Comment: It seems to me that a primarily ray casting approach would check points along a line to "cast" the ray, although this may not be typical ray casting it limits the amount of creatures you have to check both in terms of how you would query the quadtree and the fact that it won't query many creatures ahead of its eventual destination.

Comment: I guess I have been using ray casting incorrectly, in reality I want the most efficient way to do ray casting where it finds not only the node but the Creature. Also, this is being used for input to a Neural Net. I will update the question to reflect this.

Comment: The problem with checking points along the line is that it is non-adaptive - not every visible node will have a point fall in it, ones that may contain creatures. Increasing the sampling resolution (increase number of points + decrease distance between them) will be at the cost of *many* queries rather than a single one with the frustum approach.

Comment: True but I don't always need it to work perfectly. Is there a efficent way to query a quadtree only for the nodes that intersect a line?

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is unclear what this does, could you please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method can be converted into a *quadtree-ray* intersection query. A rather nice implementation in JavaScript can be found [here](https://github.com/tmpvar/ray-quadtree/blob/master/ray-quadtree.js). For each node that the ray intersects, perform the same distance query as outlined before, and return immediately when the first creature is found.